# Score for Ranked plots using scatter plot widget

Tags: orange

I'm using orange 3 and when I Score plots using the scatter plot widget how do I view the numerical score associated with the ordered list of plots. Did that feature get removed with the upgrade from 2.7 to 3?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, what was the meaning of this score?

See. This is why it was removed.

(As I recall, it was the average probability assigned to the correct class by the k-nearest neighbour classifier on the projection -- or something similar. The number is useful for ranking projections, but doesn't have any meaningfyl interpretation or absolute scale, like >0.70 is good, >0.90 is excellent. Hence there's no point in showing it.)